# Doctrine2 ORM slow query optimization

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm struggling to make a query efficient enough. I'm using Doctrine2 ORM (the query is build with QueryBuilder) and part of my query is running very slow - takes about 4s with table of 5000 rows.

This is the relevant part of db schema:

```
TABLE user
id (primary)
... (plenty of rows, not relevant to the query)

TABLE slot
id (primary)
user_id (foreign for user)
date (datetime)
```

And this is how my query looks like (it's the basic version, there's a lot of filters to be applied, but these work like fine for now)

```
SELECT 
  u.id AS uid, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT s_order.id) AS sclr_1, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT s_filter.id) AS sclr_2 
FROM 
  user u 
  LEFT JOIN slot s_order ON (s_order.user_id = u.id) 
  LEFT JOIN slot s_filter ON (s_filter.user_id = u.id) 
WHERE 
  (
    (
      (
        s_order.date BETWEEN ? 
        AND ?
      ) 
      AND (
        s_filter.date BETWEEN ? 
        AND ?
      )
    ) 
    AND (u.deleted_at IS NULL)
  ) 
  AND u.userType IN ('2') 
GROUP BY 
  u.id 
HAVING 
  sclr_2 > 0 
ORDER BY 
  sclr_1 DESC 
LIMIT 
  12
```

Let me explain what I'm trying to achieve here:
I need to filter users who has any slots between 1 week ago and 1 week ahead, then order them by count of slots available between now and 1 week ahead. The part of query causing issues is LEFT JOIN of s_filter and I'm wondering whether perhaps there's a way to improve the performance of that query?

Any help appreciated really, even if it's only plain SQL I'll try to convert it to DQL myself!

@UPDATE
Just an additional info that I forgot, the LIMIT in query is for pagination purposes!

@UPDATE 2
After a while of tweaking the query I figured out that I can use JOIN for filtering instead of LEFT JOIN + COUNT, so my query does look like that now:

```
SELECT 
    u.id AS uid, COUNT(DISTINCT s_order.id) AS ordinal
FROM
    langu_user u
        LEFT JOIN
    slot s_order ON (s_order.user_id = u.id) AND s_order.date BETWEEN '2017-02-03 14:03:22' AND '2017-02-10 14:03:22'
        JOIN
    slot s_filter ON (s_filter.user_id = u.id) AND s_filter.date BETWEEN '2017-01-27 14:03:22' AND '2017-02-10 14:03:22'
WHERE
u.deleted_at IS NULL
AND u.userType IN ('2')
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY ordinal DESC
LIMIT 12
```

And it went down from 4.1-4.3s to 3.6~

Comment: you have proper index on s_order.user_id  and s_filter.user_id (at least)

Comment: @scaisEdge yes, Doctrine adds indexes to all foreign key columns. The real issue is nested loop s_order if I take out count distinct on s_filter (which I figured out could be INNER JOIN to filter these)

Comment: nobody with any more ideas? :(